# Text not appearing in Box

Tags: virtualbox, colors, display-manager, gnome-color-manager

The text is not appearing in some dialog boxes. While terminal and file names are properly showing. Can  anyone have idea about it? I attached picture here. I tried soo much but unable to resolve.. please give precious guidance. I shall be very thankful to you.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.